# Ошибка сериализации

Tags: c#, winforms, serializable

Есть usercontrol. Добавлено свойство. Редактирование свойства в редакторе невозможно.

Класс:

```
[Serializable]
public class TableColumnTest
{ 
  public TableColumnTest() { }
  public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}
```

В пользовательском элементе:

```
public TableColumnTest Test { get; set; } = new TableColumnTest();
```

При добавлении элемента на форму, поле Test - серое. Типа нельзя редактировать.

Comment: [PropertyGrid FAQ](https://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/PropertyGridFAQ.xml). Вам нужен раздел [Как реализовать отображение составного свойства?](https://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/PropertyGridFAQ.xml#E1MAC)

Comment: Нет. Я не могу редактировать это свойство из редактора формы. Оно просто серое :(

Comment: Естественно, не можете. Редактор не знает, что такое `TableColumnTest` и как с ним обращаться. По ссылке описано, как сделать редактирование.

Comment: Вроде получилось. Спасибо.

Comment: Теперь в пользовательском элементе сделал так:
public List<TableColumnTest> Test { get; set; } = new List<TableColumnTest>();

Из редактора добавил пару элементов. При попытке скомпилировать получаю ошибку:
Ошибка  Недопустимый файл Resx. Не удалось загрузить тип "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[NNN.TableColumnTest, NNN, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", который используется в RESX-файле.  Убедитесь, что в проект добавлены требуемые ссылки

Не подскажите теперь куда смотреть?